# How do I view the total time of OOo Impress' Rehearse Timings?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-impress

I've rehearsed a talk using OpenOffice.org Impress, and I want to know the total time taken. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've rehearsed your talk, you can look at how long an individual slide took by looking at "Automatically after" in the "Advance Slide" of the "Slide transition" Task Pane. [OO.org documentation](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Impress_Guide/Using_slide_transitions#Setting_the_timing_of_automatic_slide_changes).

It'd be nice if you could view the times of each slide all at once, or better yet just get told the total.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted, since it doesn't provide a way to get the total.